# Show that $\sin(nx)\cos(x)+\sin(x)\cos(nx)\le \sin(nx)+\sin(x)$??

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I want to show that the following inequality is true when $x$ is on the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$:

$$\sin(nx)\cos(x)+\sin(x)\cos(nx) \le \sin(nx)+\sin(x)$$

I believe it to be true just from crunching numbers, but I would like an elegant way to show it. I am really new to doing proofs, so I am not sure how to proceed.

Thank you!

Comment: Since it's $\cos(nx)$, the LHS becomes $\sin(nx+x)$.

Comment: @Dr.MV - there is still an issue, though. $\sin(nx)$ and $\cos(nx)$ could be negative, depending on $n$.

Comment: But the interval was between 0 and pi/2, and n is in the natural numbers, so no they can't be negative.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, we would need absolute values to make this trivial.

Comment: My end goal is to make the LHS look like (n+1)sin(x).

Comment: @Physika; $x$ is between $0$ and $\pi/2$, but $nx$ is not if $n > 1$. And $\sin (n+1)x \ne \sin nx + \sin x$. The correct formula is $\sin (n+1)x = \sin nx \cos x + \sin x\cos nx$, which is the reason for user236182's remark.

Comment: Oh okay, I see what you mean.

Comment: It seems I need to get these little details straight, thanks for your help everyone

Comment: I get that for n = 12, x = 0.5, the inequality is false.

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a valid inequality. Consider $n=4$ then plot $\sin 5 x - \sin 4x-\sin x$, we obtain

[image]

Comment: Interesting, when plotting the difference for high values of $n$, you see a kind of envelope, which is slowly increasing. It seems to stay always below $0.5$, so that would mean that adding $1/2$ on the right would render the inequality true.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut this is true ... but I dropped the idea of correcting the inequality :-)

Comment: Ah ok, thank you very much for your help. So it seems I couldn't prove it because it is not true!